# How to implement nested column / row with flex in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement widget like `ListTile` that has `Column (2:7:1)` and `Row(8:2)` in it. 
[This is the widget I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXnfr.png)

I tried this code.

```
Widget _buildCard() {
  return Card(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 7,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 8,
                child: Container(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

But I got this error.

```
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
```

I understood what this error means, but I don't know how to avoid it.
What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the framework can't calculate the height of the items because you have an unbounded height (Because you are probably inside a ListView) and several `Expanded` in the Column, the column tries to be as big as possible, but you lack a limit on the height.

you have two choices here, give to the `Card` a vertical constraint (eg. wrap in a `Container` and set a fixed height) or give a value to `itemExtent` for the ListView

check the Column troubleshooting info on the documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html

Comment: Thank you! I I finally understand and I modified the code to as follow. It works fine.